# reset password and send email for different type of collections (Company , Customer, Admin) on their email but email can be duplicate in collections

Tags: node.js, mongodb, email

I'm making a RESTful API
there are multiple type of collections for users (Admin, user, company).

Admin (email, password)
Companies (CompanyDetails, DirectorDetails , phone, address, email , password)
Regular Users (Name, phone, email , password)

I need to send the reset password email to the user what should be the strategy.

scenario 1 (email exist in both Company and User)

1. search users from company and user
2. send an email for the accounts they have , if they have emails in both collections (for company and for user ) in email i will send the token for both accounts
3. on reset password screen i will ask for which account (for company or for user)

scenario 2 (email exist in both Company and User)

1. search email in both collections
2. SEND AN EMAIL with token for both account with (Company and User)
3. update the same password for both accounts

scenario 3 (email exist in Company or User)

1. search in both colletions
2. create token and send email
3. reset password with token to Rest API
4. search in both collections again and update the password for that who has the token for password

Comment: The issue your facing comes from bad design. I'm not sure why the collection separation happened to begin with but I recommend you change it to have 1 collection, either containing a `role` field or some sort of a "parent" collection that will only contain email / password and what not. I'm not sure exactly what your question is but obv if you keep this current structure you just have to search all collections and update all collections respectively

Comment: data with other users will be there what will do for that

Comment: If i have user of Company , I need to create the functions in schema so every user will get the data of their own Like Company will get its own and customer too

but now i have implemented a lot on this, please give some other suggestion